# Is there any information regarding Itachi's lover?

Tags: naruto

I was reading Chapter 401: Illusion of *Naruto*. Page 10:

[image: Picture Slice of page 10 from Naruto]

In the third panel, Obito comments (emphasis mine):

> [Itachi] had killed **his lover** and his father and his mother...

I found this to be a new piece of information, as I never knew Itachi had a love interest. Was anything else mentioned anywhere in the series about Itachi's lover?

Comment: I think the canonical answer is no, kishimoto Masashi has not disclosed about His lover, but some speculation can be made. Itachi spent most of his childhood with sasuke , then in his chunin and jounin period in anbu so there is less chance of making friend , so his lover can be part of anbu and to maintain the bloodline and he killed his lover , may be Uchiha , as there  are fan fiction where her name is Uchiha Aya . But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was not clearly mentioned ever but still Izumi Uchiha can be considered one.

From, Itachi Shinden: Book of Dark Night

> Itachi came to her to begin the massacre with her as he was told by
>   Danzō Shimura that he could only spare his little brother Sasuke
>   Uchiha. Believing that ending her life first would quell his inner
>   doubts, he proceeded to kill her and her mother first. As he lured her
>   mother away, Itachi approached Izumi and placed her in an extremely
>   powerful Tsukuyomi where she lived the entirety of her life in
>   0.000000001/th of a second. In her dream, she became a chūnin, retired from shinobi life to become Itachi’s wife and raise their children,
>   and lived to become eighty years old before dying of old age alongside
>   Itachi. Because her mind was departed from reality in such a manner,
>   Izumi collapsed into Itachi’s arms dying. Izumi thanked Itachi for
>   giving her the life she wanted with him, even if it was a dream, and
>   Itachi thanked her for loving him as she passed away peacefully.
>    - [naruto.wikia.com](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Izumi_Uchiha)

Even in Itachi Shinden: Book of Bright Light, its mentioned how she earned his acceptance. So killing her like this proves affection from Itachi's side too.

Answer (score 7):

Naruto Manga has ended but there has not been any information about Itachi's lover. Kishimoto Masashi has not disclosed anything about Itachi's lover but some speculation can be made.

As we know Itachi, he entered Anbu at 11 and became captain by age 13<sup>[1](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha)</sup>. And the massacre of Uchiha clan took place while he was in Anbu. So his lover may be from Anbu and the highest possibility that she is an Uchiha otherwise Itachi would have not kill her.

Mentioning about Itachi's lover, Kishimoto might be trying to show how much Itachi loves his brother and give strong hold to the plot about Itachi's relationship with his brother Sasuke. Killing whole clan and his own love but not his brother does provide strong proof about how much Itachi loves his brother

I would like to mention about fan fiction here, as anime is progressing with lots of filler, within some filler there might appear Itachi's lover. As for the fan fiction her name is **Aya Uchiha**.

Comment: There is the Itachi Shinden which is a Novel written by Kishimoto about Itachi, it has the story about Itachi from age 4 to just before the massacre, and the anime is Adapting It right now. It is Canon by normal standards, and does include at least one girl who was chasing after itachi, and itachi might have reciprocated those emotions, though details are sketchy for me as i have not read it or the summary fully.

Comment: As for that there is already another answer describing about it.

Comment: This is however the most up voted answer, albeit because of Age and stuff, I missed the 2nd answer, and likely others who wander here like i did will too.